# How to display image from a video stream using image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, video

I'm  c# begginer.I used wpf image control to show image from my camera. It's work normally in winform pictureBox but not in WPF image control. It's all blank! And I'm sure the data stream exist.

The icImagingControl1 is the control of my camera SDK.
It's can return image data in many forms. Like Intptr,Byte,Bitmap.
I want load data in image control from memory.
And the function would be triggered everytime the camera snap.
Here is my code.

```
private void icImagingControl1_ImageAvailable(object sender, XXX.Imaging.ICImagingControl.ImageAvailableEventArgs e)
        {                
            XXX.Imaging.ImageBuffer CurrentBuffer = null;
            CurrentBuffer = icImagingControl1.ImageBuffers[e.bufferIndex];
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    CurrentBuffer.Bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    memory.Position = 0;
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
                    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    image1.Source = bitmapImage;   
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Hope anyone could help me.

Comment: The BitmapImage code looks ok. Is `image1` actually part of any visual tree?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I just pull it from the toolbox and it's part of grid.

Comment: Try to save the image to a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream, and see if you can open that file in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Clemens 
Thanks for your reply. I saved it to FileStream and opened it in Windows Explorer. Every image looks normal. I think maybe it's the thread problem. I will find other solution.

Comment: You should have seen an exception then (and tell us about it in your question). Anyway, see my answer.